# Get my class instance when i use admin ajax in my plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, class, admin-ajax

im writing a plugin and i need to use ajax on it. 
I try to use admin ajax and it work but when i use it i can store var in my class.

Example : 
i got my class like

```
class Create_order{

public $product_order = array();

}
```

My methods are in the construct function

```
public function __construct() {

add_action('wp_ajax_add_products_order', array(
            $this,
            'add_products_order'
        ));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_products_order', array(
            $this,
            'add_products_order'
        ));
        add_action('wp_ajax_calcul_total_order', array(
            $this,
            'calcul_total_order'
        ));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calcul_total_order', array(
            $this,
            'calcul_total_order'
        ));

}
```

Now i'll add product in my array like
example :

```
public function add_product_order(){

    if (isset($_POST['id'])){

        $product  = wc_get_product($_POST['id']));

        $this->product_order[$product->id] = $product->name;

        echo json_encode($this->product_order[$product->id]);

        die();

    }

}
```

The problem is here when i use admin ajax i cant use $this. It's always empty...

If i dont use admin ajax from wordpress that work perfectly. The problem is when i dont use admin ajax i cant use woocommerce function.

Example wc_get_product is not defined.

My ajax

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: "POST",
     dateType: "json",
     url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
     data:  "action=add_products_order&id=" + produit_id,                
     success: function(html) {                   
         console.log(html);
         var json = $.parseJSON(html);
         //here what i want to do               
     }
});
```

My problem is i want to use Admin ajax to get all wordpress and woocommerce functions and used it like wc_get_product and store it in a variable.

Here admin ajax from wordpress dont care about my class instance.

Best regards

Comment: Because the AJAX request is a new request which re-fires (make new instances of) everything. You'll need to store it somewhere to keep record of it.

Comment: Thank for that, that why i want to do but how..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHP sessions by putting them into wordpress and after you would simply have to use `$_SESSION`

After searching I have found [this](https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/) but i haven't tested it.

Comment: I dont really understand. Should i try to open session at the start of my plugin, and when i load my page put my object in my session like $_SESSION['order'] = new Create_Order();
But after that what should i do ? When i call my function with ajax on my class $_SESSION['order']->product_order[$product->id] = $product->name; ?
I can try it.

Comment: yes thats what to do to start it and use it like you said
`add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}`

Comment: I'm on a plugin then i have to start my session on my class like 
`add_action('init', array(
   $this,
   'startSessionFunction'
  ));`
On the constrcut function and after that create my session var when i call the template to call my page plugin. like it

`public function create_order_bioco()
 {
  echo '<h1>' . get_admin_page_title() . '</h1>';
  $this->bioco_get_template('admin-create-order');
 }`

And on my template `if(!$_SESSION['order']){ $_SESSION['order'] = new Create_Order(); }`
RIght ?

Comment: I thinks thats it

Comment: I'll try and give you my feedback

Comment: your welcome ! check my solution for the people in the future !